# What's the relevance of J2EE Design Patterns?

Tags: java, design-patterns, jakarta-ee, enterprise

I'm already familiar of GoF's patterns, and I've been reading on J2EE Design Patterns (specifically, browsing [this index](http://java.sun.com/blueprints/corej2eepatterns/Patterns/)). Now, many of them are strikingly similar to either GoF's patterns and the ones in [Fowler's PEAA book](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/), what brings me to the question: besides being specific to a platform, aren't these patterns redundant? What makes J2EE patterns better suited for Java applications, since design patterns are intrinsically platform/language agnostic?

Comment: Only thing I can think of is targeted examples

Comment: Well, could you share them? Even if it's small-ish technical details, it may make a difference

Comment: "since design patterns are intrinsically platform/language agnostic" I wouldn't say that. The form pattern take differs greatly between languages, and the effect some pattern achieves becomes so trivial in some languages that it doesn't even deserve the name of a pattern.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: Wikipedia's (yeah, I know) description is a bit more aligned to my conception: "In software engineering, a design pattern is a general reusable solution to a commonly occurring problem in software design". What confuses me is that as patters are used during the _design_ phase, how does a programming language or platform affect them? I understand the case for different paradigm (OO X Functional) or different domains (Interaction x Architecture), but not for the same paradigm/domain.

Comment: Many of the J2EE patterns have become deprecated, just like J2EE itself (it's been called Java EE now for about 5 years). E.g. Service Locator has been replaced by IOC in most cases. Be careful about old J2EE patterns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the patterns in the GoF book address general OO design patterns, the J2EE design patterns address - well - enterprise/server-side/distributed applications. Some patterns were more related to work around shortcomings of the J2EE platform. But things improved since Java EE 5 (POJOs + annotations).

Have a look at this book:

[http://www.amazon.com/Real-World-Patterns-Rethinking-Practices/dp/0557078326/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1297032756&sr=8-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0557078326)

http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/real_world_java_ee_patterns

These patterns are still targeted at the Java EE stack, but I guess you could adapt them to other frameworks as well.